# UITableView Setup

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an unsorted NSArray of names.  I know how to build a static table, but I am not sure how to make a dynamic table that will have a section with the first letter of the name and then the names for that letter in put into each section.  I know this sounds like a beginner level programming question, and well it is.  Any help would be great.  New to iOS programming so I am just trying to get a feel for everything.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051009/how-to-create-sectioned-grouped-table-view-alphabetically

Comment: its hard to explain broad questions like this. try searching google for iOS+alphabetically+sorted+UITableView..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com) using the block-based data model initializer:

```
NSArray *items = ...; // and array containing your unorganized data (items of type NSString assumed here)
TLIndexPathDataModel *dataModel = [[TLIndexPathDataModel alloc] initWithItems:items sectionNameBlock:^NSString *(id item) {
    return [[((NSString *)item) substringToIndex:1] upperCaseString];
} identifierBlock:nil];
```

The `sectionNameBlock` argument is a block that returns the first letter of the given item, which the initializer uses to organize the data into sections. Then you'd use `dataModel` (instead of an array) in your data source and delegate methods using the various APIs like `[dataModel numberRowsInSection:]`, `[dataModel itemAtIndexPath:]`, `[dataModel indexPathForItem:]`, etc.

Try running the ["Blocks" sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Blocks/Blocks/BlocksTableViewController.m) for a working example.